# RecyclerView Duplicating On Back Press

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database

I load a recyclerview based on Firebase data via the following method:

```
 @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            String newPollEpoch = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                if (mNewPollsAray.contains(newPollEpoch)) {
                    Log.v("POLL_ADDED", "POLL ADDED: " + newPollEpoch);
                } else {
                    Log.v("Child_Added", "The new child is " + newPollEpoch);
                    String newPollImageURL = dataSnapshot.child(IMAGE_URL).getValue(String.class);
                    //TODO: On additional devices, numbesr are not appearing as the question
                    String newPollQuestion = dataSnapshot.child(QUESTION_STRING).getValue(String.class);
                    String convertedQuestion = newPollQuestion.toString();
                    mNewPollsAray.add(0, new Poll(convertedQuestion, newPollImageURL, newPollEpoch));
                    mNewPollsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Log.v("OnChildChanged", "OnCHILDCHANGEDCALLED " + dataSnapshot.getKey());
                }

            }



        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    mPollsRef.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);

}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mPollsRef.removeEventListener(mChildEventListener);
}
```

Here is the method I call when an item in the recyclerview is clicked:

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            view.getId();
            int itemPosition = getAdapterPosition();
            String passEpoch = mNewPollsAray.get(itemPosition).getPollID();
            Log.v("PASSED_ID", "The passed ID is " + passEpoch);
            Intent toPoll = new Intent(getActivity(), PollHostActivity.class);
            toPoll.putExtra("POLL_ID", passEpoch);
            startActivity(toPoll);
        }
```

The fragment I am loading it from is part of a TabLayout. When I navigate between the tabs the recyclerview loads correctly.

However, when I click an item in the recyclerview (which takes me to a new activity) and then navigate back to the fragment containing the recyclerview, items get duplicated and the recyclerview items are all out of order. I think it has to do with onStart() being called multiple times and essentially "stacking" new items onto the recyclerview instead of replacing them, but I was hoping to confirm.

Comment: can you post code in onCreateView() function of fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you add a listener, but never remove it. So the next time when you enter the view, you add a second listener and thus get two calls to `onChildAdded()` for each item in the database.

The solution is to remove the listener when you exit the view. Since you attach the listener in `onStart()`, you should remove it again in `onStop()`:

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    mPollsRef.removeEventListener(mChildEventListener);
}
```

Comment: I actually do have that code to remove it. Funny this is it is only when I navigate back to the fragment via onBackPressed(), it is duplicating and reordering my ArrayList() which triggers notiftyDataSetChanged() and populates the recyclerview. I have tried another way that is still causing the duplication, see updated code

Comment: The cause is still likely to be the same: while navigating you're not removing the listeners, thus adding another listener when the view comes back. I recommend setting breakpoints in the debugger to see if the listener removal triggers.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with code, I was facing similar issue got resolved with bellow changes.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(mMainLayout == null)
    {
      mMainLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,false);
...
    } 
    return mMainLayout;
}
```

When mMainlayout is not null, it mean that your fragment instance has already one instance of the mMainLayout and already added to  ViewGroup container no need to add it again. You may be facing issue as you are adding same view again to same container.

Answer (score 1):

By Clear the data set you can avoid loading of similar items again in Recycler View. It worked for me.

```
             listOftrailers.clear();

              try {

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                MovieTrailer item = new MovieTrailer();

                JSONObject js = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                item.setVideoID(js.getString("id"));
                item.setVideoName(js.getString("name"));

                item.setVideoKey(js.getString("key"));
                item.setVideoSite(js.getString("site"));
                item.setVideoType(js.getString("type"));

                String name = item.getVideoName();
                if (name.contains("Official Trailer") || 
                         name.startsWith("Official"))
                    listOftrailers.add(item);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        videosadapter = new TrailerListAdapter(listOftrailers.size(), 
                            listOftrailers, MoviePage.this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(videosadapter);
```